# How can I combine these two sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction

Please, take a look at the map, here: https://ielts-simon.com/ielts-help-and-english-pr/ielts-writing-task-1/page/2/

I want to combine these two sentence:

> 1- At the junction of Hospital Road and Ring Road, a roundabout was created.
> 2- At the junction of Hospital Road and City Road, a roundabout was created.

I am not sure, may it be right?

> For each of the junction between Hospital Road with Ring Road and City Road, a roundabout was created.

Comment: Your sentence presumes that all three intersect at one roundabout. The two sentences only state that there is a roundabout at one intersection and a a roundabout at another intersection, *which may, or may not*, be identical. Could be two separate roundabouts. You do not have sufficient information to state otherwise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two roundabouts were created on Hospital Road, one at Ring Road and one at City Road.